# Use Storyboard to customize FUIAuthPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to customize a `FUIAuthPickerViewController` (from Firebase), but it seems the only option due to the implementation is to do this from code.

Is it possible to customize a `FUIAuthPickerViewController` from a Storyboard?

Here is the recommended setup:

```
   func authPickerViewController(for authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
        return LoginViewController(authUI: authUI)
    }
```

--

```
class LoginViewController: FUIAuthPickerViewController {

    override init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?, authUI: FUIAuth) {
        super.init(nibName: "FUIAuthPickerViewController", bundle: bundle, authUI: authUI)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

}
```